# Outlook forgets the date when switching from Calendar to Mail and back

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Consider the following scenario:

1. I'm browsing through my calendar, moving backwards or forwards, trying to find something
2. I'm going back to my e-mail Inbox to check something, leaving the calendar on a specific date in the past/future
3. I come back to the calendar to find it "jumped" to today's date

I hate this behavior, especially because there's a simple "Today" button in the calendar that allows me to jump myself to today's date in a single click. I would like the calendar to remember its date when I leave it.

Is this behavior configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never found a way to do this, but you can open your calendar in a new window (right click - open in new window) and keep it open at the relevant date range in the background when you switch to your in-box.

Not ideal but OK work around I think!

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be possible, not even under the new Outlook 2010. You might want to send a feature request to the Office 2010 developer team through the Microsoft Connect so that feature versions of Outlook might contain this feature.

Other workarounds: Either keep a second window open as FoleyIsGood explained or if you are a developer you could try to create an add-on that achieves that effect.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what the others have said, this is a by-design 'feature'.

***Most*** people want to look at the calendar for "now" when they switch to the calendar page.

Typically, that's what I want, though sometimes it'd be nice if it recalled I was looking at October of next year instead of this week, but viewing 'now' makes sense, too. I generally rely on that to get me back from looking at some future point to 'now' when I need to see what else is happening this week after submitting a vacation request, for example.